# Move a row from sheet to sheet with comments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script in place (1st script implemented 1 year ago) to move a row form 1 sheet to another (within a google sheet/workbook). The problem is that is does not take the comments with it. Does anyone know how I can include any unresolved comments in the transition from sheet to sheet?

```
var objSettings = {
sheets : ['CHECK', 'STAGE2', 'READY', 'SCHEDULED', 'ARCHIVE', 'WASTE'],
shActive : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
column : 1,} function onEdit(e) {try{var sh = e.range.getSheet();if (e.range.getNumRows() == 1 && e.range.getNumColumns() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == objSettings.column) {
  var sheetName = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < objSettings.sheets.length; i++) {

        if (objSettings.sheets[i] == sh.getName().trim().toUpperCase()) {

            if (objSettings.shActive[i] == 1) {

               Logger.log(('' + e.value).trim().toUpperCase() );
               Logger.log(sh.getName().trim().toUpperCase());

                if (('' + e.value).trim().toUpperCase() != sh.getName().trim().toUpperCase()) {

                    var shDest = e.source.getSheetByName(e.value);

                    if (!(shDest)) {
                        var shDest = e.source.getSheetByName(('' + e.value).trim().toProperCase());
                    }
                    if (!(shDest)) {
                        var shDest = e.source.getSheetByName(('' + e.value).trim().toLowerCase());
                    }
                    if (!(shDest)) {
                        var shDest = e.source.getSheetByName(('' + e.value).trim().toUpperCase());
                    }
                    Logger.log(shDest);
                    if (shDest) {

                        var currRow = e.range.getRow();

                        var dataDest = shDest.getDataRange().getValues();

                        for (var j = 3; j < dataDest.length; j++) {
                            if (('' + dataDest[j][objSettings.column - 1]).length == 0) {
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        var lastRow = j;

                        for (var k = 0; k < objSettings.sheets.length; k++) {
                            if (('' + e.value).trim().toUpperCase() == objSettings.sheets[k]) {
                                var type = objSettings.shActive[k];
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        var dataR = sh.getRange(currRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();

                        if (type == 1) {
                            shDest.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, dataR[0].length).setValues(dataR);
                        } else {
                            var dataR0 = dataR[0];
                            dataR0.shift();
                            shDest.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, dataR[0].length).setValues([dataR0]);
                        }

                        sh.deleteRow(currRow);
                        Logger.log(currRow);
                        Logger.log(lastRow + 1);
                        Logger.log(type);

                      sh.getParent().toast('The row has been moved!', 'Info');

                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}}catch(e){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e);    }  }
```

Alternatively, if you think there is a better more stable way of accomplishing this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#moveTo(Range)) to cut and paste ranges with comments.

[Comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments) are a part of the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).
[Enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to use `Drive.Comments.{}`

Then you can check the `status` property for `"open" || "resolved"`

```
function moveComments () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range_one = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A10");
  var range_two = ss.getSheets()[1].getRange("A10");

  // Get a list of all comments in the workbook
  var workbook_comments = Drive.Comments.list(ss.getId()); 
  /* 
    var comment_cell_value = workbook_comments.items[0].context.value;
    var check_status = workbook_comments.items[0].status; // "open" || "resolved" 
  */

  // Move the range with comments to another sheet.range
  range_one.moveTo(range_two);
}
```

- See also [Manage Comments and Discussions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-comments)